# React how to pass a component with its props to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I need to pass a wrapper to the component Test. This wrapper could be anything and it needs to have its own props (function, bool, string, whatever).

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Yo</h1>
      <Test Wrapper={<CustomWrapper text={"yes"} />} />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The component Test receives it as a prop and renders it including the children (here 'Nope')

```
function Test({ Wrapper }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <div>Nope</div>
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What is the right pattern to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using the `children` prop?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-neumann-wlbvy - here is actually what i've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the child as a prop would work

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Yo</h1>
      <Test Wrapper={CustomWrapper({ text: "yes" })} />
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const Test = ({ Wrapper }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper children={<div>Nope</div>} />
    </div>
  );
};

const CustomWrapper = props => ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
      {props.text}
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image]

[image: Edit awesome-mccarthy-mpxji]

Comment: ok but what if you need to pass props to CustomWrapper and only applicable to CustomWrapper ?

Comment: @Nicc Updated, kindly check it would be appreciated

Comment: how to make it work if the CustomWrapper is actually a class ? it does seem to accept that

Comment: @Nicc Sorry tried with no success, however, I guess this has been a good practice. There is no cost for functional components, now and future. Still, if someone could make it, feel free to make an edition. Finally, if you like, kindly accept it as the answer.